# Changing android emulator's IMSI number results with networks connection

Tags: android, networking, emulation

For a test requirement, I modified the IMSI number in emulator.exe via a hex text editor,replaced a new IMSI number instead of original '310260000000000'. I ran the emulator again and resulted in no network connection any more. Any one who knows the problem and a way to resolve it pls give me a reply, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you fix it:

1. Make sure your host machine is connected to the internet,
2. Start a web-proxy tool such as paros proxy or web-scarab on your machine.
3. Now start your emulator: adb somename
4. goto Settings -> Wireless & network settings -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names
5. Click on menu. It will show you an option for "New APN"
6. Give any Name say "myapn". Any APN say "testapn". Proxy = 127.0.0.1. Port = 8080 (check the port of your web-proxy tool).
7. Click on menu again and save.

You should have internet connection now. G'd luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, while that procedure makes the emulator show there's 3G connectivity, no traffic ever reaches the proxy.
It's a good step in the right direction though.